# Why might PhantomJS fail to work on the Travis CI container-based infrastructure?

Tags: php, phpunit, phantomjs, travis-ci

I'm using [Spiderling](https://github.com/OpenBuildings/phpunit-spiderling) and PHPUnit to functionally test a PHP project, often using PhantomJS as the underlying browser. This works totally fine in Travis CI using the legacy infrastructure.

I've switched to `sudo: false` in my `.travis.yml` to try moving to the Docker-based infrastructure, and all PhantomJS-based tests fail. In fact I have added two new trivial tests, and find that if Spiderling is switched to a simple cURL-based fetch, everything is fine:

```
/**
 * Check to see if any tests are working on Travis containers
 * 
 * (This succeeds)
 * 
 * @driver simple
 */
public function testAnythingAtAllSimple()
{
    $text = $this->visit(self::DOMAIN)->find('.container')->text();
    $this->assertContains('Questions about this site', $text);
}

/**
 * Check to see if any tests are working on Travis containers
 * 
 * (This fails - identical except for the driver)
 * 
 * @driver phantomjs
 */
public function testAnythingAtAllPhantom()
{
    $text = $this->visit(self::DOMAIN)->find('.container')->text();
    $this->assertContains('Questions about this site', $text);
}
```

My Travis YAML configuration is thus:

```
language: php
sudo: false
php:
  - "5.6"
notifications:
  email: false
before_script:
  - phantomjs --help
  - composer self-update
  - COMPOSER=composer.travis.json composer install
  - git submodule init
  - git submodule update
  - npm install bower
  - bower install
  - mysql -u root < test/build/create-user.sql
  - export PATH=`pwd`/bin:$PATH
  - cp config/env-config.php.example config/env-config.php
  - touch /tmp/phantom-awooga.log
script:
  - phpunit --coverage-clover=coverage.clover
  - wget https://scrutinizer-ci.com/ocular.phar
  - php ocular.phar code-coverage:upload --format=php-clover coverage.clover
  - cat /tmp/phantom-awooga.log
  - cat /tmp/awooga-screenshot-data.log
```

I've added `phantomjs --help` to prove that PhantomJS is indeed available in this new infrastructure, and this renders the usual help output as expected. I am not installing this myself - it is the default install within Travis build machines.

In another test, I have tried a `sleep(3)` after a `$this->visit()`, which makes no difference. I had wondered if Phantom just needs more time to settle down in the new environment.

I've also tried the Spiderling/Phantom feature of making a screenshot, and I just get a large transparent image (it's a valid PNG, but it has nothing on it).

I wonder if Spiderling is accidentally suppressing some errors in PhantomJS that is causing the difficulty? PhantomJS does start up correctly, it just won't render. I've turned on connection logging programmatically, and it is logging OK, but there are no obvious error messages:

```
Starting server on port 4516
Recieved command  POST /url http://localhost:8090
  Executing command  POST /url http://localhost:8090
http://localhost:8090 fail
Recieved command  POST /elements .//descendant-or-self::*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' container ')]
  Executing command  POST /elements .//descendant-or-self::*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' container ')]
Recieved command  POST /elements .//descendant-or-self::*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' container ')]
  Executing command  POST /elements .//descendant-or-self::*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' container ')]
Recieved command  POST /elements .//descendant-or-self::*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' container ')]
  Executing command  POST /elements .//descendant-or-self::*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' container ')]
```

The `http://localhost:8090 fail` doesn't look good, but it does not explain what the problem is.

My limited understanding of the new infrastructure is just that `sudo` is not permitted. However I do not use root permissions anywhere in my build.

This issue isn't *too* important, as the tests work fine on the legacy infrastructure. However since it is "legacy" I presume it will be withdrawn at some point, so it makes sense to get this working if possible.

PhantomJS offers a `--debug` switch, but unfortunately Spiderling does not offer a clean way to add it. I've therefore use a post-Composer hack to overwrite the necessary file in the Travis configuration, and this approach does result in appended `DEBUG` info in the log. However, I can't see anything useful.

Since this might be a problem with Travis, I've [raised a bug](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4785). In the meantime, any observations about the differences in the legacy and container environments that could cause this problem would be most welcome.

Comment: To me it seems like there's a problem to resolve 'localhost' to 127.0.0.1. Probably you could try to pipe the PHPs Server log to a file and see if the requests find their way to the server? Simply specify a logfile path instead of `/dev/null` in `browser/scripts/server.sh`

Comment: @tillz, that's not a bad idea re the DNS mapping, I've had that problem for certain fussy installs of PDO. I'll try switching to the numeric format and will see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Yep, that should be a workaround if DNS is the problem. Another possible problem is that `php -S localhost:4242`, it won't respond to `curl http://127.0.0.1:4242`, so if the host gets resolved to early, it may fail. try changing it to `php -S 0.0.0.0:4242`

Comment: Aha, thanks @tillz, that's helped a lot. Connecting to the app on `127.0.0.1:8090` didn't make a difference, but then also listening via `php -S 127.0.0.1:8090` has made a big change - 2 tests failed rather than 20+! There is something awry though, as my build time increases from 2:05 minutes (successful on old infra) to 6:04 (fails on new container infra).

Comment: My guess is that Spiderling is being kept busy with retries, and the two remaining failures are flakiness due to the current slowness.

Comment: Does `0.0.0.0` mean "any interface available? I am not familiar with that notation.

Comment: Jep, 0.0.0.0 makes it listen on all interfaces

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89831/discussion-between-tillz-and-halfer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the people experiencing the same problem:

Apparently, there seems to be a bug anywhere between the Client in the tests and the Webserver in resolving the hostname `localhost` to the IP `127.0.0.1`. This bug might be in PhantomJS or in PHP, because calling `curl` directly works fine.

The easy fix/workaround is to modify the tests to call `http://127.0.0.1:port` and modify the server configuration to listen on `127.0.0.1`. As there's no need to resolve the hostname to the loopback-IP, it's no problem for the client to fetch the webpages from the PHP-builtin webserver.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I'd never have thought of this `:-)`. I've updated the report at Spiderling, and will do so for the Travis one in due course.